# react how to style : styled-dropdown-component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to change the `color` and the `size` of the `DropdownMenu` using the `styled-components` like the code below:

```
const DropdownCustom = styled.DropdownMenu`
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
`;
```

Then I try to use it like this:

```
 <Dropdown>
            <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>Create</button>
            <DropdownCustom hidden={!state}>
              <DropdownItem>Action</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Another action</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>Something else here</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownCustom>
 </Dropdown>
```

But it gives me an error saying that `_styledComponents.default.DropdownMenu is not a function`.

I am very new to styling with css and it is very confusing, so any advice or guide would be really appreciated! :)

**Edited**

```
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu
} from "styled-dropdown-component";
```

Comment: I don't know what the DropdownMenu component is, could you attach it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to style a custom component you need to use [`styled` as a function:](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#styled)

```
const DropdownCustom = styled(DropdownMenu)`
  font-family: ...
`;
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-franklin-jkn96]

It will work only if the [custom component uses the `className` props.](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components)

Therefore, you sometimes want to style custom component's parent, and target the styling with selectors - as it's just a CSS:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  font-family: ...;
  .dropDown {
    ....;
  }
`;

<Wrapper>
  <Dropdown />
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Thank worked :). I got one more question tho. For example, I could change the `border` by writing `border: none;` but how could find other `options` like changing the background color when hovering. Where could I find all these options?

Comment: You need to debug the styling, try using the dev tools of your browser, or you can just dig in the component's docs - no one can't guess without reading the API.